# How to stop unexpected tab interaction when using full screen web view in Chrome on Android Tablet

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, tablet, touchscreen, browser-tabs

While using the Chrome browser application on my tablet, some pages and html based games have the ability to shift the page into 'full screen' browsing mode, which hides the tabs and such from the top of the page.

However, I've discovered that said 'hidden tabs' are NOT actually hidden from interaction while in this mode! If there is a button or link that the game or page has near the top of the 'full screen', and you 'click them' via touch screen, it can and WILL change to the tab hidden behind it or even close it, depending on where you click.

The only way to safely interact with any such buttons or links at the 'top' of a full screen web page is to drag down the page, expose all the menus and tabs, THEN click on the now lower button or link to safely activate or follow it.

This is VERY frustrating when you need to hit said button a dozen or so times.

Is there a way to make it so you can't interact with the tabs in Chrome Browser when said tabs are hidden from view?